# Windows Explorer default file arrange mode for folders with media files

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, metadata

Wondering if it is possible to disable the default file tags that we are presented with in Windows Explorer when dealing with folders that contain media files. By default in Windows 10 if a folder contains media files we are presented with the following defaults for arranging files:

[image]

#, Title, Contributing, artists, Album etc

Since none of this metadata is relevant to me (or even saved in .wav files), I am wondering if I can remove this default behavior of Windows and restore it to how other folders present tags to organize files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go up a level in the folder hierarchy, right click on the folder, select "Properties", select the "Customize" tab, and then set "Optimize this folder for" to something other than *Music* or *General Items* (*Documents* is probably what you want).

If none of the standard types meets your needs, you can right-click on a column heading in that folder, select "More..." from the popup, and choose which details you want. In the "Choose Details" pane that appears, check the attributes that you want, uncheck the ones that you don't, and use the 'Move Up' and 'Move Down' buttons to set the order (top down is left-to-right).